# ContainerRequestFilter ContainerResponseFilter doesn't get called

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey, jax-rs, httpresponse

I am trying to learn jersey by creating a small RESTful service. I want to use the Filters for  specific reasons(Like I want to use the **ContainerResponseFilter** for **CORS** headers to allow cross domain requests). However, I am just not able to get these filters intercept my call. I have seen all the posts for this problem and most of them say to register with annotation provider or in web.xml.
I have tried registering the files in **web.xml** as well as giving a `@Provider` annotation for the container

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e194 -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/config/BeanLocations.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.example</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
            <param-value>com.rest.example.cors</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.example.CORSFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.example.RequestFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Here are my Filters:**

```
package com.rest.example.cors;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest creq,
            ContainerResponse cresp) {

             cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
             cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
             cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
             cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");

            return cresp;
    }
}


package com.rest.example.cors;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

@Provider
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("request filter");
        return request;
    }
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/pratiktest/SpringTemplate) to my github project.

Comment: What container/app server and version of Jersey are you using? Also, have you tried registering your filters in your Jersey Application class?

Comment: Im using jersey version 1.8. Im using the VMware VFabric that comes with STS. How do we register the filters in jersey application class?

Comment: To register your filters, add them to the `getClasses` method in your  `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` object although it appears your web.xml should be handling that for you. Are your REST methods are being called? How do you know your filters aren't being called?

Comment: My REST methods are called. I set a debug point in my Filters and the code never hits the debug point, however it hits the resource methods.

Comment: just add packages details which contain all the filters in your ResourceConfig. I have posted one exapmle also.

Comment: ContainerResponseFilter's param-value is pointing to the wrong package/class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I added a Jersey Application class and registered the filter in the class, which solved my problem. Also upgraded my jersey version to 2.x from 1.x

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    /**
     * Register JAX-RS application components.
     */
    public MyApplication () {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(CustomerResource.class);
        register(Initializer.class);
        register(JerseyResource.class);
        register(SpringSingletonResource.class);
        register(SpringRequestResource.class);
        register(CustomExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked for me in Jersey 2.24 deployed in Tomcat 8.5 but I also had to register the application class in `web.xml` as follows: `<init-param><param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name><param-value>MyApplication</param-value></init-param>` (inside the servlet definition for `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`)

Comment: Absolute wonderful! I totally forgot to add it to my ApplicationClass. Thank you a lot for that tip.

Comment: What is the definition of `register`, and what are the dependencies for this solution?

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem on Wildfly 10 / rest easy like this (CORSFilter is my ContainerResponseFilter):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        resources.add(CORSFilter.class);

        return resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was my problem too.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>org.anchepedheplatform.infrastructure.core.filters.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

First, I wrote a class which implements `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter`

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

/**
* Filter that returns a response with headers that allows for Cross-Origin
* Requests (CORs) to be performed against the platform API.
*/
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

  @Override
  public ContainerResponse filter(final ContainerRequest request, final ContainerResponse   response) { 
      final ResponseBuilder resp = Response.fromResponse(response.getResponse());
      resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
      final String reqHead = request.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
      if (null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals(null)) {
      resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);}
      response.setResponse(resp.build());
      return response;
 }
```

and  later I had put this reference of this class in **intit-param** web.xml.

Comment: Is the code you provided taken from here [CORS-Compliant REST API with Jersey and ContainerResponseFilter](http://blog.usul.org/cors-compliant-rest-api-with-jersey-and-containerresponsefilter/) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending the `ResourceConfig` class the process of registering all the providers can be tedious one and chances are there that one can even miss few providers.

What here can be done with a type of `ResourceConfig` is you can use packages method in the default constructor to specify the `packages("")` which will contain your rest resources and the providers. For Instance lets say we have a package `com.test.poc.rest` which contains all the rest services and another package namely `com.test.poc.providers` then our resourceConig will look like:

```
public class CustomResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig{
    public CustomResourceConfig(){
       super();
       packages("com.test.poc.rest;com.test.poc.providers");
       //register any custom features
       register(JacksonFeature.class);         // enabling JSON feature.
    }
}
```

and boom jersey will now scan for your webservices annotated with `@Path` and for the providers annotated with `@Provider`.