# CORS Response Filter not invoked Resteasy / JAX-RS 2.0

Tags: filter, cors, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to implement a CORS response filer to allow cross-domain reference from my JavaScript front-end. I am using `Wildfly 10.0.final` which comes with Resteasy that is `JAX-RS 2.0` compliment if I understand correctly.

EDIT: added @Provider to the CorsResponseFilter, and as a singleton to the RestServiceConfig.

What do I need to do to get my CorsResponseFilter invoked?

PS. Read these posts, but they didn't help solving the problem.

[ContainerRequestFilter ContainerResponseFilter dosent get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670885/containerrequestfilter-containerresponsefilter-dosent-get-called)

[ResourceConfig and Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440321/resourceconfig-and-application)

CorsResponseFilter.java

```
@Provider
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://podcastpedia.org"); //allows CORS requests only coming from podcastpedia.org       
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");        
    headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
}
```

}

RestServiceConfig.java

```
public class RestServiceConfig extends Application {

    private final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public RestServiceConfig() {
        singletons.add(new CorsResponseFilter());  
        singletons.add(new ApplicationService());
        singletons.add(new TweetObsService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.mycorp.myapp.service.RestServiceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>org.clearbyte.obs.service.CorsResponseFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/service</param-value>
</context-param>

...
```

Wildfly log console

```
13:56:01,672 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.clearbyte.obs.service.RestServiceConfig
13:56:01,672 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.clearbyte.obs.service.TweetObsService from Application class org.clearbyte.obs.service.RestServiceConfig
13:56:01,672 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.clearbyte.obs.service.ApplicationService from Application class org.clearbyte.obs.service.RestServiceConfig
```

Comment: I've tried that but I get the same result.

Comment: Add a `@Provider` annotation on it and see what happens. You still need to add it to the `singletons` though

Comment: I'm not sure if it works with RESTeasy, the way the request processing is handled. What I _do_ know is that RESTeasy already has it's own CorsFilter. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29390508/2587435). You can just use that filter

Comment: Do I need to declare the use of the build-in CORS filter in web.xml and do Wildfly 10.0.final include RestEasy 3.0.9?

Comment: You can't. It needs to be configured programmatically, meaning you cannot just use standard JAX-RS API dependencies. You need to have the resteasy-jaxrs dependency. After you configure it the way you want, just add it the singletons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've started over from scratch with a new project to eliminate error sources. Thanks for the input on using `@Provider` and adding `OPTIONS`. Plus I removed all configuration REST from the web.xml.

@Provider is essential for the Filter to work

ServiceCorsFilter.java

```
@Provider
public class ServiceCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");                       
    }    
}
```

@ApplicationPath makes web.xml configuration obsolete

ServiceConfig.java

```
    @ApplicationPath("service")
public class ServiceConfig extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public ServiceConfig() {
        singletons.add(new UserServiceV1());
        singletons.add(new ServiceCorsFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

This is what is left in the web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <!-- No REST related config due the the @Provider and inheritance of Application-->
</web-app>
```

Comment: By annotating your ``ServiceConfig.java`` with ``@ApplicationPath("/service")`` you should be able to drop pretty much the entire servlet and context setup from ``web.xml``.

Comment: Correct I've have updated the web.xml and the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try declaring it like a standard filter, not a param of the servlet dispatcher:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsHeadersFilter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.clearbyte.obs.service.CorsResponseFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>CorsHeadersFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (namely: Chrome) send an OPTION request before issuing their request.
Since you explicitly specify 'GET' 'PUT' 'POST' 'DELETE', the 'OPTION' call does not get the headers information :)

Adding OPTION to your list should solve the issue